# How to draw a line parallel to another in a 3-point perspective when they do not pass through a vanishing point?

Tags: geometry

For instance, below, the points $P$, $O$ and $N$ belong to the upper side of the parallelepiped.

[image: parallelepiped in 3-point perspective with 3 points on the upper side]

How to draw a line, belonging to this upper side too, and that would be parallel to $(ON)$ and pass through $P$?

It is possible to use the other vanishing points $F_1$ and $F_3$ too (vertical and horizontal directions respectively).

I am absolutely clueless about this question. (I don't see if there's any way to use cross-ratios to solve this; anyway I'd prefer a geometric solution if possible).

The geogebra file can be retrieved from [this link](http://docs.teotleco.org/segment_on_parallelepiped.ggb).

Comment: I think you want two point perspective.  I am not familiar with the math behind it, but I would not be surprised if some googling would give you what you want.

Comment: The line through $ON$ has a separate vanishing point from $F_2$. You want your line through $P$ to share that vanishing point. I believe it should be along the same horizontal line as $F_2$, though.

Comment: Googling led me to a lot of drawers explanations, not mathematicians, and they always tell how to draw lines that pass through the vanishing points... @Arthur this leads to a realistic result, but how to know if this is mathematically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line $EF$ is parallel to the view plane, then the answer is easy: the vanishing points of all lines parallel to plane $EFGH$ lie on a "horizon line" parallel to $EF$, which is the intersection between the view plane and the plane parallel to $EFGH$ passing through the point of view.

Then you just need to draw from $F_2$ the line parallel to $EF$ and produce $ON$ to meet the horizon line at $Q$: line $PQ$ is the required parallel to $ON$.

[image]

If $EF$ is parallel to $GH$ but not to the view plane, then $EF$ and $GH$ meet at a second vanishing point $F_3$. Line $F_2F_3$ is then the horizon line and the construction can be continued as explained above.

Comment: OK, on this drawing $EF$ is really close to be parallel to the view plane. I should ask another question with a "better" 3-point perspective. I guess you mistyped $OQ$ (instead of $PQ$).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo. I corrected it and added the case when $EF$ in not parallel to the view plane but is parallel to $GH$.

Comment: OK, and thanks for the complete explanation (case when $EF$ is not parallel to the view plane).